# Android MediaPlayer persistent cache using ExoPlayer

Tags: android, caching, streaming, media-player, exoplayer

I'd like to implement a persistent cache for streamed audio data in my app.

I've scoured the internets and looked at the few existing solutions, most of them require you to create a local proxy, which writes the data to cache as well as serving it to Android's built-in MediaPlayer.

I finally came across Google's ExoPlayer which appears to do exactly what I want it to! I believe in order to create the cache I need to use CacheDataSource, however I can't figure out how to use it!

I've been through the Google documentation and demo app but they don't provide much info about caching at all.

Could anybody help me out and provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Never used this but the following tutorial on how to construct an audio renderer seems pretty straight forward to me. http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html#datasource

May I ask why you want to implement persistent caching with a media player? When I made use of google's MediaPlayer framework it seemed pretty useful to me, never had a problem with streaming as long as I have a data connection.

Answer (score 0):

I had also been searching endlessly for a solution for caching audio for the purpose of offline playback availability.

I finally found this library:
https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache

Also it is called Android Video Cache, it works for caching audio as well.